# Replicate CentOS Server for Local Testing Server

Tags: centos, replication

I have a CentOS 6.4 Server running ruby 1.9.3, ruby on rails, with nginx, Unicorn, postgras SQL

I would like to copy the WEBSERVER to a local machine to use for development purposes.

I have installed CentOS, ruby, rails, nginx, postgras SQL and unicorn on my local machine already..

is there a way to use SSH to copy filesystem? or some alternative

What i want to do is take my web-server... and pretty much duplicate the entire machine... MIRROR COPY that is fully functional independently... so i can modify and test new additions before i put it in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you have already installed webserver (nginx) to both servers, since that what exactly are you trying to copy?

Surely you can use `scp -r <src> <dest>` in order to copy some folder from one peer to another or `rsync -avz <src> <dest>` if you're trying to synchronize the same directories on different approach.

Since you are using RHEL-like Linux distro, you can simply create image of your physical server and deploy it on the local machine as virtual machine. Use [virt-p2v](http://libguestfs.org/virt-v2v/) for that.

Comment: What i want to do is take my web-server... and pretty much duplicate the entire machine... MIRROR COPY that is fully functional independently... so i can modify and test new additions before i put it in production.

Comment: @Big Al Ruby Newbie, I think that you actually don't need to copy the physical server to your workstation. Testing is common task for developers, but nobody do it in that way. Simple deploy the server from the scratch again in your virtual environment (use [virt-manager](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Virtualization/sect-Virtualization-Managing_guests_with_Virtual_Machine_Managervirt_manager-Starting_virt_manager.html) for that) and feel free to modify them.